# esp32 rssi based tracking - Consultation

Tags: esp32, tracking, strategy-pattern

I am trying to build an asset tracking solution with esp32. I am looking out here for an optimal strategy, than an answer to a specific question.

I've set 3 esp's as anchors, and I have another 5 esp's left to act as assets. Currently I am running AP in the assets and scan from anchor repeatedly. The anchors are interconnected through tcp connection and info is exchanged about the rssi to each of the assets, which is fed to my linux server, where I run other algorithms to deduce the relative location.

But this seems to be battery intensive on the assets. Also scanning limit for more numbers from anchors could be an issue when I'd want to scale this to 100s of assets.

Is there a better strategy to implement this?

Comment: WIfi is battery-intensive.  What are your distances?  Could you use Bluetooth instead?

Comment: I am looking to try it in about 300 sqft or about 27 sq mt of space. An open room, with very few pillars around. If placed properly, the distance could be upto 15m. Using BLE is an alternative I can consider.